# Connecting ESP8266 to Virtual IP Address / Websites

Tags: sockets, tcp, arduino, shared-hosting, esp8266

I'm using the ESP8266 wifi module to send/receive packets on the web from my microcontroller. In particular I've been using the

`AT+CIPSTART="TCP",'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,80\r\n`

command to pick which endpoint I'm sending packets to. It currently works with static IPs (or domains with static IPs); but I have yet to find a resource saying how this could work with virtual IPs (or domains with virtual IPs).

I have websites hosted on shared servers, but every-time I execute this CIPSTART command (with IP or domain), the response is of the generic shared server IP address page.

**How can I get my ESP8266 to connect with my specific site that is hosted on a shared server with a virtual address?**

Resources I've read:

- [ESP8266 AT Command Set](http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-doc/ESP8266ATCommandsSet.pdf)
- [ESP8266 AT Command Examples](http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-doc/ESP8266-AT-Examples.pdf)

Comment: By "virtual IP" do you mean dynamic IP which changes over time or a virtual host where there is a single static IP, but hosts multiple websites on different domains?

Comment: Virtual host with single static IP and hosts multiple domains.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the domain name, as the DNS will automatically resolve the IPs for you. Be careful about the length value. You should add at least 4 characters to the actual length of the GET string to account for the carriage return / new line feeds:

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80   
AT+CIPSEND=80
GET http://api.thingspeak.com/update?key=PBG7CKSZU6FU3M4C&field1=5 HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a virtual host, you connect normally to its IP and port with `AT+CIPSTART`.

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",80\r\n
```

The important part is when you send the HTTP request with `AT+CIPSEND`.
For the web server to distinguish between different virtual hosts, you need to add a [`Host` HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Client_request) into the request.

```
GET /request.php?key=value HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.example.com\r\n
\r\n
```

With this, the web server should return from the right host and not the default one, from the host provider.

Comment: I don't see how this connects to ESP8266. I've already tried using domain-names with the AT+CIPSTART and the http response is the generic one served from the shared IP address, not the one from the specific domain.

Comment: @DevonBernard I edited the answer to make it clearer.